# How does one check for null or an empty result set with MySQL C++ connector?

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

In the following code, the intention is to check for null,but the code keeps throwing exception.

```
 pstmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM test ORDER BY id ASC");
 res = pstmt->executeQuery();
 res->next();
 if(res->isNull(1))
 {
     cout << " In null";
 }
 else
 {
     cout << " Is not Null";
 }
```

How does one check for null or an empty result set?

Comment: Just a guess, does `next()` return a result?

Comment: No, a quick check  showed that  next failed.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how to fetch data from the database:

```
sql::Connection *con;
sql::Statement *stmt;
sql::ResultSet  *res;
// ...
stmt = con->createStatement();
// ...

res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT id, label FROM test ORDER BY id ASC");
while (res->next()) {
  // You can use either numeric offsets...
  cout << "id = " << res->getInt(1); // getInt(1) returns the first column
  // ... or column names for accessing results.
  // The latter is recommended.
  cout << ", label = '" << res->getString("label") << "'" << endl;
}

delete res;
delete stmt;
delete con;
```

> The API for fetching result sets is identical for (simple) statements
>   and prepared statements. If your query returns one result set, use
>   sql::Statement::executeQuery() or
>   sql::PreparedStatement::executeQuery() to run your query. Both methods
>   return sql::ResultSet objects. The preview version does buffer all
>   result sets on the client to support cursors.

Read more [mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-results.html)

In other words, use either the next() function or previous() function in the sql::ResultSet which is returned by executeQuery().

Comment: I have had a similar issue. The ResultSet pointer variable got nullptr sometimes.
And I have fixed the issue by deleting the ResultSet variable after every time use.
Meaning if ResultSet* is created and used, it must be deleted like 'delete res'